# how to executre capistrano 3 pre db:migrate step

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I am using the latest capistrano version 3, and rails 4, ruby 2. I want to copy and file and create a soft link just before the db:migrate step. I dont see any docs on how to do this.